# Taking a train from Scotland to London

Tags: scotland

Do I need a passport to travel from Scotland to London? Is there any border patrol or immigration office that requires documents to re-enter the UK by train?

Comment: Travel from Scotland to England is entirely within the UK, so there is no re-entry of the UK on such a journey.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a passport, or indeed any form of ID, to travel between Scotland and England. Both countries are part of the UK, and as such there are no border controls between them. All you need is a ticket* for the train!

*Some tickets, like Interrail or possibly Britrail tourist passes, will require a passport to prove that you're *not* a British citizen, and thus eligible for the cheaper tourist passes.

Comment: My parents once took a bus tour from England to Scotland, and when nearing the border the tour guide told them to get out their passports as it was possible (but not always) to encounter immigration officials.  But of course "this" time they were lucky and the border crossing wasn't manned.

Comment: Just for others who may miss the point, @Peter M’s comment is of course ironic.